# Nightmare hangs on goto()

Tags: node.js, headless-browser, nightmare

I have been recently working with NightmareJS and I am now having a problem. It seems as though whenever I try to load a page using Nightmare and wait for a selector to exist, it hangs on the goto call. I have the following code and the only thing printed to console is "loading".

```
nm = new Nightmare({show: false});

console.log("loading");

nm.goto("https://www.google.com")

.then(() => {
  return nm.wait(".gbqfba")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("search bar loaded, showing browser");
    nm.show();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.toString());
  })
})
.catch(error => console.log('An error occurred:', error));
```

(the class 'gbqfba' is a hidden part of the search bar that I wait for so I know the bar is loaded)

Comment: Are you sure it is the `goto` which is blocking and not the `wait`? Maybe a console log immediately inside goto's `then` would make it clear? Because from what I see, gbqfba is not a class, but an ID (so # is needed instead of .)

Comment: @Vasan I tried what you suggested, and it didn't log anything. All I got from it was a window like such: http://prntscr.com/f18qnl . Also, as I can see, the element I am referring to _is_ in fact a class, but correct me if I'm wrong: http://prntscr.com/f18nl1

Answer (score 0):

nightmare.show() is no more a function and you need to set it during initialize.To view nightmare's renderer window, you need to pass

```
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
```

Also, you can turn on the Developer tools, so that you can manually check if document.querySelector(".gbqfba"); is working.

```
var nightmare = Nightmare({
   openDevTools: true,
   show: true
});
```